# handlebar json - html conversion

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars.js

I need to convert this json data into a table with 3 columns: property name, property source and property value. Could you please help?

```
  "result": {
      "total": 100,
      "config": {
        "propName1": {
          "source": "propsrc1",
          "value": "propval1"
        },
        "propName2": {
          "source": "propsrc2",
          "value": "propval2"
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: this doesnt work :   {{#result}}
                       {{#each config}}
                        <tr valign=top>
                            <td>{{property}}</td>
                            <td>{{value}}</td>
                        </tr>
                       {{/each}}
                    {{/result}}

Answer (score 1):

Your object is a simple one. You want to iterate over each property of `result.config` and print its key, its `source` value, and its `value` value in 3 separate `<td>` elements.

In the Handlebars documentation for the [#each built-in helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration), the following is stated:

> Additionally for object iteration, {{@key}} references the current key name

This tells us that `object` iteration is supported by the #each helper and that we can print each key with `{{@key}}`.

Our template is straightforward one:

```
{{#each result.config}}
    <tr valign=top>
        <td>{{@key}}</p>
        <td>{{source}}</td>
        <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/ayg286mc/) for your reference.